# Check if browser remember password is disabled using Geb/Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, geb

We have created a login page that prevents the browser offering to remember the password. Is there a way using Geb/selenium to test if this works?

[image]

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Hi there are various ways to do that 1. open chrome in private mode/incog mode -by default no browser remember.2.use if in java robot class.3.use sikuli or autoit to handle browser specific dialogs 4. use chrome profiling please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21472761/click-chrome-prompt-box-to-save-password